# How to convert SVG icons using webpack?

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am working on a react and Webpack 3 application.

I have a set of SVG icons and want to convert these icons into images and put it into images folder so that I can access these images and use it in my react component(eg. `<img src='icon.png' />`).

Currently, I am exporting SVG as components in js and importing it in JSX.

Should I use webpack loaders for this? if yes, which loader I should use?
or any other ways?

Comment: Hi, why do you want to use .png instead .svg?

Comment: @SoldierCorp To reduce the rendering time as am including all SVG's in a JS file. So If i emit images then i can make a request to those images separately.

Comment: You can do that with svg's too though can't you?

Comment: I am developing an azure-devops extension, and azure does not accept SVG files

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SVG to PNG loader](https://github.com/github1/svg-to-png-loader).